# F# type declaration based on parameter passed

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

hey i want to generate a parametrized type in F#
if parameter is present then generate an array of float containing as many number of values as value of parameter
else single float value

i tried the code which is showing error

```
type val<'mult> =
                 |Some -> Arr[|1..mult|]
                 |None -> value
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not achievable directly. Have a look at F# type providers.

Comment: Are you trying to generate a type or a value?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly F# doesn't currently have [dependent types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type).  Also see this [uservoice](http://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5749571-add-support-for-primitive-sub-types-types-constra) asking for pretty much the same thing you want.